# Sizing jQuery Tabs panels

Tags: jquery-ui

[image: tabs]![https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuAxZ.png])

I am using jQuery tabs and I like how the tabs align to the left and the top orange portion takes up 100% of the allotted width. But somethings when I click on the tab, the drop down panel only has enough info for half of the page.

How can I adjust the panel size so all the panels only take up half of the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add class style to every displayable tab content and constrain it's height.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>Two</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-3"><span>Three</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="fragment-1" class="tabview">
        Tab1 content
    </div>
    <div id="fragment-2" class="tabview">
        Tab2 content
    </div>
    <div id="fragment-3" class="tabview">
        Tab3 content
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS style that also displays scrollbars if necessary:

```
.tabview {
    height: 50px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Here is working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fhhu5/